# What is the coefficient of $y$ in the equation of the tangent line? $y = 2x^2 + 4x$; at $(-2,0)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the general equation of the line tangent to the equation below at any given point.

What is the coefficient of $y$ in the equation of the tangent line? $y = 2x^2 + 4x$; at $(-2,0)$

Please elaborate every exact part such as: What is the constant? What is the slope? And what is the coefficient of $x$ if its ever even there?

The quizzes I took are under the stupid assumption that I know all of these terms.

**Edit:**  The derivative is $4x + 4$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What have you tried?  For instance, have you found the derivative?

Comment: 4x + 4, what's next?

Answer (score 0):

**Strategy:**  The tangent line to a curve at the point is a line passing through the point whose slope is equal to the derivative at that point.

1. Find the derivative of the function.
2. Evaluate the derivative at the point.  That is the slope of the tangent line.
3. If the point is $(a, b)$, then the equation of the tangent line is $$y - b = m(x - a)$$ where $m = f'(a)$.

In this case, $(a, b) = (-2, 0)$.  You correctly found that $f'(x) = 4x + 4$, so $m = f'(-2)$.  I'll leave the remaining details to you.